# Drawing Left and Right arrow with XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to draw a left and right arrows like the following up and bottom arrows:

```
//up arrow
        <Path Data="m 4 14 4 0 0 -9 3 0 -5 -5 -5 5 3 0 z"
            Fill="#571CB61C"
            Stroke="#FF00B400"
            StrokeThickness="1" />
//bottom arrow
      <Path Data="m 3.5 0 4 0 0 8 3 0 -5 5 -5 -5 3 0 z"
            Fill="#571CB61C"
            Stroke="#FF00B400"
            StrokeThickness="1" />
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you're not able to convert the path data, apply a RotateTransform to the Path's RenderTransform.

Comment: With RotateTransform it's working , thank you

Comment: It may also be worth to learn the path markup syntax, and convert the data. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax

Comment: you're right, thank you

Comment: Building simple geometries by hand is certainly do-able. The difficulty level ramps up pretty quickly though. I use syncfusion metro studio which is a (free) library of geometries and InkScape. With InkScape I can grab any of the free bmp ico or whatever off the web and use it's bitmap trace facility to generate a geometry.

Comment: @Clemens, it might be worth adding that as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the arrows in chart with zoom function and I need them to be precise, here are the final arrows:

```
        <!--  Left Arrow  -->
       <Path
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Data="m 290 10 5 -5 0 2.5 8 0 0 4 -8 0 0 3  z"
            Fill="#571CB61C"
            Stroke="#FF00B400"
            StrokeThickness="1" />
    <!--  Right Arrow  -->
    <Path
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Data="m 4 14 4 0 0 -9 3 0 -5 -5 -5 5 3 0 z"
        Fill="#571CB61C"
        Stroke="#FF00B400"
        StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterX="2" CenterY="8" />
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
```

it is quite easy and it is explained here :
https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/streamgeometry/
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way so you don't have to rely on anyone in the future

1) first download [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) then install it then go to [flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/).

2) second search for the icon that you like then download its `svg` format.

3) now, open the icon in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and after you select it.

4) go to the menu bar then `Path -> Object to Path`

5) then go to `File -> Save As` then change the save type to `.xaml`

all what you have to do now is copy the results from the .xaml file and paste it in your app.

here is a sample of my results using the following icons [left arrow icon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/left-arrow_156887), [right arrow icon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/right-arrow_156876)

[image][image]

```
<!--thin left arrow-->
<Path Data="M 401.166 478.097 113.178 245.004 401.166 11.903 391.536 0 88.834 245.004 391.536 490 Z" Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="10"/>
<!--thick left arrow-->
<Path Data="M 410.312 454.729 151.767 244.996 410.312 35.271 381.693 0 79.688 244.996 381.693 490 Z" Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="10"/>
```

[image][image]

```
<!--thin right arrow-->
<Path Data="M 96.536 490 403.019 244.996 96.536 0 86.981 11.962 378.496 244.996 86.981 478.038 Z" Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="10"/>
<!--thick right arrow-->
<Path Data="M 106.601 490 412.15 245.004 106.601 0 77.85 35.856 338.702 245.004 77.85 454.159 Z" Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="10"/>
```

PS: i believe this can work on any svg icon.